# Kotlin in Android: how to extract String with an if statement in it?

Tags: android, string, kotlin

I want to extract this string below, so I can provide an other language.. but the problem is, I have an if statement in it.. any Solutions?

```
 .setMessage("Delete selected ${if (count > 1) "items" else "item"}?")
```

Comment: Use `Context::getString` method instead of hardcode literals

Comment: @Héctor I would, but I can't, cuz there is code in it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `Context::getString` method several times inside yor string template:

```
.setMessage("${context.getString(R.string.delete_selected)} ${if (count > 1) context.getString(R.string.items) else context.getString(R.string.item)}?")
```

where

```
R.string.delete_selected = "Delete selected"
R.string.items = "items"
R.string.item = "item"
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: There's also `Context.getString("Delete selected %$1s", ...)` which allows you to place the "items" word anywhere, and it may vary between languages.

Comment: A good example of a swap would be english/french `red car` vs `voiture rouge` (car red)